# Ruby on Rails: validate when context is not given value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I update record by passing context:

```
employee.attributes = employee_params
employee.save(context: :age_related_fields)
```

and I know that in model I can conditionally apply validation only for given context

```
validates :date_of_birth, on: :age_related_fields
```

but is there a way how to use negation in the `:on` condition?
e.g.

validate `date_of_birth` when context is NOT `:personal_fields`.

Answer (score 9):

There is a rejected pull request on rails for what you're looking for.

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/30710

The same task also has a workaround though:

```
validates :title, presence: true, unless: -> { validation_context == :test }
# or in your case
validates :date_of_birth, unless: -> { validation_context == :age_related_fields }
```

EDIT in 2024:

This is no longer a workaround. It is documented and is the intended way of solving this.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html#method-i-validation_context

Comment: This seems to be implemented now: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html#method-i-valid-3F

Comment: `validation_context` seems to have been made an official part of the API. So it's no longer a workaround, but the expected way to handle this. There is still no explicit opposite of `:on` though as far as I can see. Thanks for pointing this our though, I updated the answer.